# How to adjust the columns in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I am wondering if it's possible to move the columns in Google Drive with your files.

I know in Windows Explorer it is possible (see screenshot 2)

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible in Google Drive. Currently, you are not able to re-order the position of individual columns nor remove/disable individual columns and not even adjust the width of individual columns (best you can have is to resize the browser window to shrink column width).

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible workarounds for this problem.

1. Hiding side panel (like shown in the screenshots below)
   [image: The side panel of Google Drive changes the column sizes of Google Drive]
2. Zoom out (Control + minus key) on browser - zoom percentage 90%
   Press Ctrl + minus key to adjust zoom of the browser window. Most of the times, it works on 90% zoom. you may get to see the full view of the file/folder names You can also try to zoom in - Ctrl + plus, may be a couple of more times - upto 150%.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this without finding an answer. However, in Chrome, you can switch from List View to Grid View. This means that you can see the full title and a preview of each file. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I just found you can actually resize the column with file names towards the LEFT , move the mouse between the name col and the list of folders to its left , you'll see the double arrow [image]

Comment: Welcome Luca.  The question asks how to manage the columns in Drive similar to Windows explorer.  They are looking for ways to re-order the position, remove/disable, and adjust the width of individual columns.  While adjusting the space allocated to the left menu (folder list) will adjust up/down the space available to the list of file name column, this doesn't fully answer the question and adds little to existing answers. Suggest adding this as a comment to [@user0's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/128897/how-to-adjust-the-columns-in-google-drive/128907#128907)